# Can I use an external hard drive on my tablet?

Tags: tablet, usb-c

I'm wondering if I can use a hyper 5-in-1 USB-C hub with my x8max tablet so I can connect an external hard drive.it would make my life easier to just plug the drive into the tablet instead of copying files to an SD card or some other way to transfer large files. It would also make the tablet a lot more usable for other projects that I am thinking of. Any input on this would be very helpful.

Comment: can you clarify if it is "Honor X8 Max"

Answer (score 0):

Android does support connecting USB Storage device. The speed of reading/writing would however, depend on the USB port (if it is a 2.0 port, it will be comparatively slower than a 3.0 port), but it should just work.

Comment: Have you actually tried an external hard drive ?  Should work is not good enough!

Comment: @RohitGupta the tablet is OTG enabled. I have already tested it by connecting a USB hub with a mouse, keyboard, and external SSD to my tablet's OTG port. Will this information persuade you?